# Within a dataframe, copy selected cells based on filter critera to another row within the same dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to copy the value of cells based on a filter of another cell to specific rows

```
import pandas as pd

sales = {'Flight Number': ['LX2104', 'LX2104', 'LX2104', 'LX2105', 'LX2105', 'LX2105', 'LX2106', 'LX2106', 'LX2106'],
     'STD Departure': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
     'Bircher': [200, 210, 90, 40, 20, 10, 10, 30, 20],
     'Carac': [140, 215, 95,40, 50, 30, 40, 30, 50]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sales)
```

I would like to copy the cells "Bircher" and "Carac" from rows with the "Flight Number" LX2104 to the rows with "Flight Number" LX2105". The values in "STD Departure" should stay unchanged

Comment: Could you add the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, it can be more visually clearer:

```
df.loc[df['Flight Number'] == 'LX2104', 'Bircher'] = df[df['Flight Number'] == 'LX2105'].Bircher.values
df.loc[df['Flight Number'] == 'LX2104', 'Carac'] = df[df['Flight Number'] == 'LX2105'].Carac.values
```

Output:

```
  Flight Number  STD Departure  Bircher  Carac
0        LX2104              0     40.0     40
1        LX2104              1     20.0     50
2        LX2104              2     10.0     30
3        LX2105              0     40.0     40
4        LX2105              1     20.0     50
5        LX2105              2     10.0     30
6        LX2106              0     10.0     40
7        LX2106              1     30.0     30
8        LX2106              2     20.0     50
```

Also you can use, but I think it is more unclear:

```
df.loc[df['Flight Number'] == 'LX2104', ['Bircher', 'Carac']] = df[df['Flight Number'] == 'LX2105'][['Bircher', 'Carac']].values
```

I will try to explain this code. I use `df.loc[raw_index, column_index]` to get a slice (correct raws and columns). This `df['Flight Number'] == 'LX2104'` will return a boolean array with True-values where a flight number is LX2104, so we have a needed raws and then I just pass column names to have a needed columns. In right side I do the same but with another flight number. Be careful, if they have not the same length (number of raws) it won't work.

Comment: Great code and explanation. It worked. Thank you very much